# Meaning of "He didn't take me in"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> One evening when he was being particularly obnoxious, chattering away well above my head, I let him have it. 
>   "Mummy," I said, "do you know what I’m going to do when I grow up?" 
>   "No, dear," she replied. "What?" 
>   "I’m going to marry you," I said quietly.
>
> Father gave a great guffaw out of him, but **he didn’t take me in**. I knew it must only be pretence. 
>   And Mother, in spite of everything, was pleased. I felt she was probably relieved to know that one day Father’s hold on her would be broken.

Dose it mean:

1) I was not deceived?

or

2) he did not notice me?

this text is from a short story named: My Oedipus complex

Comment: It means _"I was not deceived"_.
In general, to be taken in means you have been fooled or are the victim of some deception.

Comment: Thanks @Perer Jennings, so shouldn't we use passive form if we mean "deceiving". Here it is not in passive form. I mean it should be: I was not taken in.

Comment: @ViserHashemi You can say either *he didn't deceive me* or *I wasn't deceived by him* (active or passive). The same is true of *take in*. There is no *requirement* that it be one way or the other.